# With-open should be a vector . -- But it is a vector

Tags: file, clojure, io

I am trying to read the input.txt file that is in my resources directory of a leiningen project and I get the  "Parameter declaration "with-open" should be a vector" but it looks to me like it is a vector

```
 (defn read-freq 
   (with-open [rdr (io/resource "input.txt")]
     (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
       (println line))))

 Parameter declaration "with-open" should be a vector
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function lacks a parameter vector.

Line 1 should read:

```
(defn read-freq []
```

Comment: Thanks . -- guess that was obvious but I'm a newby

Comment: No worries. The error given is not the most beginner-friendly.